# Delphi - Inheritance function result

Tags: delphi

Hi all this is a Delphi code

what is The error is this code ...

The result of Templyoe.fullName Function Not show the inherited result of Tperson.fullname Function what is the reason???

any help plz??
..........................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................

```
 program classes;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  SysUtils;

type
  Tperson = class(TObject)
    firstName : string;
    lastName : string;
    function fullName : string ; virtual;
  end;


  Temploye = class (Tperson)
  function fullName : string ; override;
  end;

  var
  person : Tperson;
  Emp : Temploye;


{ Tperson }
function Tperson.fullName: string;
begin
    result := firstName + ' ' + lastName;
end;

{ Tempolye }

function Temploye.fullName: string;
begin
result := 'hi ' + inherited fullName + ' You are in Temploye Function';
end;


begin

  person := Tperson.Create;

  person.firstName := 'code';
  person.lastName := 'programmer';

  writeln(person.fullName);
  person.Free;
  Emp := Temploye.Create;



  writeln(emp.fullName);
  emp.Free;

  readln;

end
```

Comment: Would you edit your question to include the actual output (and expected output) please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You did not assign values of first name and last name in the Emp object and so they default to empty strings.

You assigned values to the person object, but that is a different object, a different instance. If you want the Emp object to have data, you will need to assign it.

It would appear that you have a fundamental misunderstanding concerning the difference between a class and an instance. I suggest you revisit that topic in your text book.

I would advise you to take more care with spelling and letter case. Your code looks messy and that usually indicates a lack of attention to detail.

Comment: but I make the result of the function is inherited from the fullName function of the Tperson class should print the fisrt and last name that stored in Tperson.firstName and Tperson.lastName

Comment: Do you know what an instance is? Those variables belong to the instance rather than the type.

Comment: Ummmmmmm thanx alot David :)